# Fake GORM mapping for results of an ad-hoc query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'd like to use Grails to build application which is a front-end to a complex data search and analysis system written already as a set of stored procedures in a RDBMS (here, oracle).

I'd like to instantiate objects of some class I written as a wrapper against rows of some dataset returned from a stored procedure. For this class I don't need to have any GORM mapping at all, I want to execute the query manually and instantiate these objects from it's rows. Those objects will never be changed and written, as the whole DB should be read-only, only session information can be stored.

Hibernate can do all this, and it has "Immutable" and read-only entities for this, but when I tried to mark this entity as "Immutable" I didn't have much success.

Is it possible to create such a fake mapping and at all, should it be created?
What are other possible ways to do this ?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a GORM object? If Hibernate has adequate support you can use it's mapping with Grails. It can be written in Groovy with javax.persistence annotations and it works with grails dynamic finders. I can write an answer with an example if you want.

Comment: an example would be great to have...
I don't insist on it being a domain class, but I have short experience using Grails and just don't know how to do this otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that in GORM, but you can use plain Hibernate with Grails.

Add your classes in the src/groovy folder. One example, in src/groovy/example:

```
package example

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Table
import javax.persistence.Column
import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable

@Entity
@Table(name="first_result")
@Immutable
class FirstResult implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L

    @Id
    Integer id

    @Column(name="name")
    String resultName

}
```

(You can also write POJOs in src/java but then you need to write constructors, getters and setters)

And in the grails-app/conf/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
      <mapping class="example.FirstResult" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Then, in your controllers and services you can use:

```
example.FirstResult.findAllById(1)
```

or any other method that works on domain classes in Grails.